# Frame only around theorem in scientific two column poster

Tags: theorems, framed, beamerposter

I am creating a poster in beamer,
I would like to have frame only around my theorem, not to the end of the page (especially having two columns), if anyone know how to modify the code to do that?

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage{multicol} % This is so we can have multiple columns of text side-by-side
\columnsep=100pt % This is the amount of white space between the columns in the poster
\columnseprule=3pt % This is the thickness of the black line between the columns in the poster
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mdframed}
%\newmdtheoremenv{theo}{Theorem}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Specify colors by their 'svgnames', for a full list of all colors available see here: http://www.latextemplates.com/svgnames-colors
\usepackage{times} % Use the times font
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} % For math fonts, symbols and environments
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows wrapping text around tables and figures
\usepackage{shadethm}
\newshadetheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\definecolor{shadethmcolor}{HTML}{EDF8FF}
\definecolor{shaderulecolor}{HTML}{45CFFF}
\setlength{\shadeboxrule}{.2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{thm}
Some important theorem.
\end{thm}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Select the code and press ctrl+k (as I did) to format it here on TEX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `\framebox` command in such way:

```
\framebox[width][position]{
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{thm}
Some important theorem.
\end{thm}
\end{multicols}
}
```